# csv writer saves file as .txt in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm sorry if this is obvious, but my code is very simple, so I don't understand where it's going wrong. I'm using the csv module to read one file which contains info from two different sources (L and R) and splitting it into two new files. The problem is, when it creates the new files, it creates them as .txt files, which I've never seen before in csv writing.

```
import csv
with open('dataset1.csv') as csvfile:
    filein = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open('dataset1Left', 'w', newline = '') as fixleft: 
        fixleftwriter = csv.writer(fixleft)
        with open('dataset1Right', 'w', newline = '') as fixright:
            fixrightwriter = csv.writer(fixright)
            for row in filein:
                if (row[2] == 'L'):
                    fixleftwriter.writerows([row])
                elif (row[2] == 'R'):
                    fixrightwriter.writerows([row])
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: If you want `.csv`, specify it explicitly - `with open('dataset1Left.csv', ...)`. They are just text files with a specific format.

Comment: The csv module does not create the output file, you do, using `open` with write access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to python, you probably don't know that pandas is perfect for dealing with csv files. To do the same thing you did, the code in pandas would be

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv',header=None)
a[a[2]=='L'].to_csv('dataset1left.csv',index=False,header=False)
a[a[2]=='R'].to_csv('dataset1right.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

The only reason I would not prefer that solution is if your file were huge, exausting the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
with open('dataset1.csv') as csvfile:
    filein = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open('dataset1Left.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fixleft: 
        fixleftwriter = csv.writer(fixleft)
        with open('dataset1Right.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fixright:
            fixrightwriter = csv.writer(fixright)
            for row in filein:
                if (row[2] == 'L'):
                    fixleftwriter.writerows([row])
                elif (row[2] == 'R'):
                    fixrightwriter.writerows([row])
    csvfile.close()
```

In words, add the `.csv` extension to the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('dataset1.csv') as csvfile:
    filein = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open('dataset1Left.CSV', 'w', newline = '') as fixleft: 
        fixleftwriter = csv.writer(fixleft)
        with open('dataset1Right.CSV', 'w', newline = '') as fixright:
            fixrightwriter = csv.writer(fixright)
            for row in filein:
                if (row[2] == 'L'):
                    fixleftwriter.writerows([row])
                elif (row[2] == 'R'):
                    fixrightwriter.writerows([row])
    csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a file extension:

```
with open('dataset1Left', 'w', newline = '') as fixleft: 
...
with open('dataset1Right', 'w', newline = '') as fixright:
```

These both need a file extension to get the `.csv` extension:

```
with open('dataset1Left.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fixleft: 
                       ^^^^ This is needed
...
with open('dataset1Right.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fixright:
                        ^^^^ This is needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `with open('dataset1Left', 'w', newline = '')`
Try to add the extension to the file:
`with open('dataset1Left.csv', 'w', newline = '')` like this